# Convert String to Date not working properly

Tags: java, date, spring-mvc, simpledateformat, java.util.date

I am getting a date by ajax in String format. But it is getting changed when I am converting it to date by SimpleDateFormat. The month is always changed to Jan. I am worried only about the month change.My code is given below

```
String appointmentDate = request.getParameter("appointmentDate");
System.out.println(" appointment date in String format "+appointmentDate);
```

Here I am getting the date correctly(16/12/2015). But when I am changing it to Date format it is getting changed(Fri Jan 16 00:12:00 IST 2015). Whatever I input the month, say August, May, June, I am always getting month Jan.

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/mm/yyyy");
Date parsedDate = dateFormat.parse(appointmentDate);
System.out.println(" appointment date in DATE format "+parsedDate);
```

Please help me out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: "But when I am changing it to Date format it is getting changed(Fri Jan 16 00:12:00 IST 2015)." You appear to think a `java.util.Date` has a format. It doesn't. If you want to format it in a particular way, use `DateFormat.format`.

Comment: @Jon Skeet Thanks for your valuable information. The return type of DateFormat.format is String, but I want it in type of Date.

Comment: Then you already have it as a date, but you're complaining about the *formatting* ("But when I am changing it to Date format it is getting changed(Fri Jan 16 00:12:00 IST 2015)") which means you're complaining about a *string* representation. Or were you only worried about the month changing? I've reopened the question, but it would help if you would edit the question to be clear about the problem.

Comment: Yes you are right. I am only worried about the change of month. But the problem has been solved now. I put 'dd/mm/yyyy' instead of 'dd/MM/yyyy'.

Answer (score 0):

As per the [`JavaDoc`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html), lower case `m` denotes *minutes*, not months.

Changing your expression to `dd/MM/yyyy` should fix the issue.

Comment: Thank you very much. I got the answer. I don't know how could I make this silly mistake.

Comment: @abhishek You can avoid this kind of mistake by copying an example of working code (from StackOverflow or [Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html)), run it alongside your problem code to verify. Then compare it to your code, tweaking to match until problem is uncovered.